# Getting Result of $q's Resolution or Rejection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking at a `$q` example from [Mastering Web Application Development with Angular](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book?tag=dp/masteringwebwithangularjs-abr1/0913).

For this code, how can I retrieve the String result of `pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve(...)` or `pizzaOrderFulfillment.reject`?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $q) {

    var Person = function(name) {

        this.eat = function(food) {
            return name + " is eating " + food;
        };

        this.beHungry = function(reason) {
            return name + " is hungry because" + reason;
        };
    };

    // success
    var pizzaOrderFulfillment = $q.defer();
    var pizzaDelivered = pizzaOrderFulfillment.promise;

    var man = new Person("man");

    pizzaDelivered.then(man.eat, man.beHungry);

    pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve("chicken");
    // TODO: var successResult = "man is eating chicken"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would tend to put your assignments inside of the promise callbacks:

```
pizzaDelivered.then(
  function(food) {
    $scope.successResult = man.eat(food);
  }, 
  function(reason) {
    $scope.failureResult = man.beHungry(reason);
  });
```

Then, in Angular, you can use these scope variables in your views and they will appear once the promise resolves:

```
{{successResult}}
{{failureResult}}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AVEUkTvG0ZwIdlf6tX3H?p=preview)

Comment: Rather than mutate the state of `$scope.result`, can a value simply be `return`ed?

Comment: No, what is returned from `then` is a new promise, which allows you to [chain promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises). Remember that promises are used for async tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Since `resolve` and `reject` happen asynchronously, setting any resulting variables must happen within a callback:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $q, $log) {

    var Person = function(name) {

        this.eat = function(food) {
            return name + " is eating " + food;
        };

        this.beHungry = function(reason) {
            return name + " is hungry because" + reason;
        };
    };

    // success
    var pizzaOrderFulfillment = $q.defer();
    var pizzaDelivered = pizzaOrderFulfillment.promise;

    var man = new Person("man");

    var successResult = null;
    pizzaDelivered.then(function(food) {
        successResult = man.eat(food);
    }, function(reason) {
        successResult = man.beHungry(reason);
    }).finally(function() {
        $log.info("successResult: %s", successResult);
        $scope.output = successResult;
    });

    pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve("chicken");
});
```

Here is an example of it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/VLa2qcD4XUDcO3Wo8mUl?p=preview

---

I made another example that demonstrates the asynchronous nature of `$q` by using [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout).  It also has two promises, one being resolved and the other being rejected: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rq715C7NmhvXnao2i9xy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about promises here, you add callbacks(using then) that are fired when you "reject\resolve" the defered object.

In your case you need to assign the var inside the promise.

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $q) {

        var Person = function(name) {

            this.eat = function(food) {
                return name + " is eating " + food;
            };

            this.beHungry = function(reason) {
                return name + " is hungry because" + reason;
            };
        };

        // success
        var pizzaOrderFulfillment = $q.defer();
        var pizzaDelivered = pizzaOrderFulfillment.promise;

        var man = new Person("man");

        // This was commented out just so you can see this example.
        //pizzaDelivered.then(man.eat, man.beHungry);

         var successResult = null;
         pizzaDelivered.then(function(food){
             successResult = man.eat(food); // var successResult = "man is eating chicken"
             console.log(successResult);
         });

       // You can add more callbacks to "pizzaDelivered" using commas as you did in your main example.

        pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve("chicken"); // after resolving the defered object the callbacks are suppose to run.
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R77Bq/).